# Custom Button Doesn't work with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, android-custom-view, motionevent, ontouch

I have a problem with **OnTouchListener**. I created a custom button. This button properly works with **onClick event**. But it doesn't work with **onTouch Event**

This is my custom button. I want only two options just button and button_pressed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button2_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button2_pressed"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button2" />
```

This is my **Ontouch button code**. When I keep the button pressed, audio is playing and looping. When I release the button audio is stopped. This code correctly works but it doesn't work with my custom button. So when i have my finger on this button, then when I release the button or when I hold the button shortly, in every case this button show me only button2.png (above the custom button code)

```
pl6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();
    switch (eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

            n6=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audio4);
            n6.start();
            n6.setLooping(true);
        return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
       n6.stop();
       n6.release();

        break;
    }

    return false;

}


});
```

This is my other button. it is correctly work. This button is a normal button just click and play.
When i pressed the button button2_pressed is appear and when I unpressed button2 is appear.

```
play2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         stopPlaying2();    
    m2=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound2);
    m2.start();



    }
});
```

Comment: Upon pressing the button it will become focused. I'm guessing the second item in your selector always resolves to true, hence `button2_pressed` keeps being displayed. You could try commenting out that specific item to confirm.

Comment: button2_pressed doen't appear with this event. Only button2 appear. This custom button code work with onclick event. I add to above text my other code. But it doesn't work with onTouch event some things might be different on custom button code but I dont know.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem again on my own. Lets explain;
Firstly I clonned all button for example btnPlay1 and btnPlay1c
but the buttons xml different to each other. the difference is only id and custom button xml file. I used 2 custom button xml I show below.

First Custom button **mybutton1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
</selector>
```

Second custom button **mybutton1c.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
</selector>
```

And example from my buttons. **clone button is invisible.** (btnPlay2c)

```
 <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlay2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/mybutton1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlay2c"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/mybutton1c"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </FrameLayout>
```

Lastly, this is my java file. When I pressed the button, button clone is showing and when I unpressed normal button is showing. That's all.

```
pl10.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();
    switch (eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

            n10=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audio7);
            n10.start();
            n10.setLooping(true);
           ///focus here\\              
            pl10c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
       n10.stop();
       n10.release();
      //and here\\\        
     pl10c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
    }

    return false;

}


});
```

This solution might be tiring but its solve the problem.